# IE10 - Need to change CSS cursor to "pointer" on mouseenter on <span> within a contenteditable <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-10

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     <span class="optional">Optional</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.optional {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When I hover over the optional class span in IE, it does not change the cursor from text type to pointer type.
When I hover over the optional class span in Chrome, it does work.

Is there a workaround for this in IE?

Comment: Thank you for editing and replying. Unfortunately, I had already reviewed the referenced link and it does not help. I am working with a html5 document which doesn't appear to operate from the three doctypes in html4.1. For that reason, I don't think that fix is an option - although I'm all ears.

Comment: I don't necessarily mean you need to use that answer. I just marked the question as a duplicate because that's what it is. Chances are if there isn't an answer on that question that fulfills your needs, it's not possible. Good question though.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
.optional:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also did not work for IE.